# Connect SwipeCellKit to custom cell with override - Swift

Tags: swift, xib, custom-cell, downcast

When I load my UITableViewController that populates with custom (xib) cells, my app crashes with error:
**Could not cast value of type 'SwipeCellKit.SwipeTableViewCell' to 'GreenHarvestAlpha.ListCell'.**
Yet, `ListCell` has the grandparent class `SwipeTableViewCell`.

If I don't downcast, class `ListViewController` won't connect to the custom cell (and I get buildtime errors that my custom cell's properties don't exist).

**Custom cell**

```
class ListCell: SwipeTableViewCell {
```

**Swipe class**  (dequeues cell)

```
`class SwipeVC: UITableViewController, SwipeTableViewCellDelegate {

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.cellSwipeIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SwipeTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self    
    return cell     }

func updateModel(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //leave empty. override in CategoryVC & ListVC with delete from realm functionality
}
```

**List class** (**crashes** with downcast error):

```
class ListViewController: SwipeVC

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath) as! ListCell
```

Also, I'm already overriding *prototype* cells in another class and this process is working for that.

Comment: Is ListCell registered in ListViewController?

Comment: @neprocker yes and print statement confirms it